# Install of GSL under Ubuntu 16.04 fails -- how do I make it work?

Tags: compiling

I have done this years ago under Red Hat Linux with no problems (installed via terminal of course).  I was doing the same thing under Ubuntu 16.04.  I got the latest tarball from gnu for gsl and then I did the

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and the last step is where it failed.  The first place where it had an error was

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 gsl_sys.h '/usr/local/include/gsl'
```

and this got an error message from the system as

```
/usr/bin/install   Cannot remove '/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_sys.h' : Permission denied
```

It went on after that, finally stopping where it complained that

```
Recipe for target 'install recursive' failed.
```

Comment: Are you running the last command as root? don't forget you need root permissions to add/remove stuff from system directories such as /usr/local i.e. `sudo make install`

Comment: Yep, you can only install as root so sudo make install.

Comment: I did do 'sudo make install' but then I had problems with the executable after it was built -- it would not run, giving an error message similar to what you get when you run an old executable on an updated OS (problem with shared library file(s)).